# Using nearest neighbours to fetch 3 closest neighbours without a target variable

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor

I am writing a program to fetch 3 nearest neighbours for each data point in my dataset. My dataset has 47 features with 5000 row entries and no target variable. I am using this [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors) to fit my entire dataset as a numpy array. I am developing the following code but seemed to be stuck :

```
X = df.to_numpy()

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
def findsuccess(id):
    nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3)
    nbrs.fit(X)
    pred = nbrs.kneighbors(X,3)
    for i in pred:
       print  "What should come here" ?? - I need to print my 3 neighbours here at this step
```

Post this I want to use the `findsuccess` function to pass the id for which I am looking for neighbours and print this list in excel as well. For example :

then function call :`# findsuccess(1234)`

The end goal is to see 3 nearest neighbours from my `id` 1234 from my dataset. The end goal is to print these three neighbours in an output file like this :

```
id        Neigh1  Neigh2  Neigh3
1234      1334    1444    1555
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `kneighbors_graph` method of `NearestNeighbors` would work for you. It returns 1 (if the particular point is k nearest neighbour) or 0 matrix.

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors_graph)

```
>>> X = [[0], [3], [1]]
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
>>> neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2)
>>> neigh.fit(X)
NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2)
>>> A = neigh.kneighbors_graph(X)
>>> A.toarray()
array([[1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1.]])
```

You can do something like this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
X = df.to_numpy()
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3)
nbrs.fit(X)

def findsuccess(id):
    neighbors_f_id = nbrs.kneighbors_graph([X[id]]).indices
    print  ('Neighbors of id', neighbors_f_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. I have two questions: what is  i = <get the index of id> ? How should I get the index of id here? And the second question, how should I get the data in the output as I have mentioned in my question. Thanks again!!

Comment: if your id is the index, then you can leave that step. `neighbors_f_id` will have the id of the neighbors, you can format the way want after that.

Comment: Perfect. Yes Id is my index. Let me try this. I hope this works. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried your solution. So while I am doing a function call findsuccess(1234) it is giving me an error. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. How.to solve for this one?

Comment: just change `x[i]` to `[x[i]]`.

Comment: I did that. Now while doing the function call I should simply write : findsuccess(1234) and this should give me three nearest neighbours? Correct? or do I need to do something else?

Comment: ya, should be enough.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting this error. ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). Why would this be coming here? I am getting error at this line : neighbors_f_id = np.where(nbrs.kneighbors_graph([X[i]]))[0]

Comment: sorry, it was sparse matrix. That's why my previous solution was not working. Try the updated solution.

Comment: Perfect! Worked! Thank you so much!